# Update background color jquery input inside td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a table with tr that have this pattern

```
<tr>
        <td width="37" align="left"></td>
        <td width="200" align="left">
            <input type="submit" name="s1" onclick="ChangeThis(this);" value="Update Color" id="s1" class="btn-blue">&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input name="info1" type="text" maxlength="6" id="info1" style="color:Red;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:normal;width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td width="340" align="center">
            <input name="extra1" type="text" maxlength="200" id="extra1" style="width:330px;">
        </td>
        <td class="hide"></td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is onclick on this button which will have the same sequence matching the input    example    button id=s1   input id =info1
I want to change the background color.  I prefer jquery or javascript is fine.   I thought about the regex with   starting with  ..   ^  ..

```
function ChangeThis(x) {
   $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="text"]').css('backgroundColor', 'Yellow');
}
```

That doesn't work,  I tried   tr instead of td

**UPDATE/EDIT**

So Essentially what I want is that When the button is clicked that there are predefined things to change in the text

1. Font Color
2. Bold or not
3. Background Color

[image]

Comment: `this` in your code refers to the global `window` object. Use the passed `x` parameter instead.

Comment: you should not use inline-javascript. very bad coding style. try to split up your html, css and javascript. you can simply add an onclick event listener inside a javascript block and don't need the inline-javascript.

Comment: @Vohuman you are right. sry. deleted my comment. never saw that js-style in jquery.css() function code before. I didn't know that this style is also valid. Learning every day a new thing: check ;)

Comment: Do you want the textbox in the 'Schedule' column or 'Extra Info' column to change (or both)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the screenshot, I've made a final update below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ok, I think I understand what you'd like.
Let me know if this fiddle solves it:

https://jsfiddle.net/14ymd0pd/

---

Based on your description, I'm a little confused as to what you'd like.

I've created a JSFiddle with what I think is the intended functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/tvu08yrm/

The main differences involved separating out the JavaScript, using the jQuery `on` event handler:

```
$('.color-btn').on('click', function(){
```

adding a new class (`color-btn`) so the buttons could be targetted and changing the functions which trraverse the DOM Elements.

A couple of notes:

- You should not be using inline JavaScript. I've separated out the JavaScript in my fiddle.
- Since I can only see a small section of code it's hard for me to say, but if the page isn't going to be displaying tabular data then don't display it in a table...use a `div` or `ul` or another relevant element, just not a table.
- I haven't done it in my fiddle, but you should also move the inline css out of the markup and into an external css file.
- The JavaScript is dependant on the structure of the table, if you change its structure you'll also need to update the jQuery selectors. This can be avoided by following a naming convention in the table rows and using these to target the appropriate elements instead of their relative positions.

Let me know if the fiddle answered your question :)

Comment: Yes,  Thank you  that is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to get your code working.

First solution: use x instead of this inside the function

- pro: code works
- contra: bad coding style and you should not use inline javascript.

Second solution: change `onclick="changeThis(this)"` to `onclick="changeThis.call(this)"`

- pro: the code works, and you can use this in function context
- contra: you use this in function context... there are only a few situation to do that. this is not such a situation. and again: inline-javascript

Third solution: don't use onclick.

```
<tr>
        <td width="37" align="left"></td>
        <td width="200" align="left">
            <input type="submit" name="s1" value="Update Color" id="s1" class="btn-blue">&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input name="info1" type="text" maxlength="6" id="info1" style="color:Red;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:normal;width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td width="340" align="center">
            <input name="extra1" type="text" maxlength="200" id="extra1" style="width:330px;">
        </td>
        <td class="hide"></td>
</tr>

$('input:submit[name="s1"]/* or a different selector... depends on your logic */').click(changeThis);
```

you should use the third one.

Comment: Sure I prefer the 3rd way,   I cannot get the function to change the color though     function ChangeThis(x) {
   $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="text"]').css('backgroundColor', 'Yellow');
}